# How to solve error in converting to R Markdown

Tags: html, r, pdf, r-markdown

Newly, I have a problem creating a Rmarkdown file (pdf, HTML, etc.) in R. I did not have this problem before, and could create Rmarkdown files without any problem. But now it is about three days that I see the following message (error):

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.17 is being loaded, but >= 0.21 is required
Calls: :: ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
```

Could you please let me know how to solve this error?

Comment: You are using an outdated package version of `xfun`. Try `install.packages("xfun")` and try to knit it again.

Comment: Thank you. It works now based on your solution.